# How to encode json in java for Android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to encode some data to JSON format and sent the same to PHP Server script to store to mysql. I am able to encode the data in JSON format but when transimmting the same to PHP I get a "\" backlash on doublecoloum. Below is how my output look like.

```
[{\"enquiry_no\":\"1\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"2\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"3\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"4\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"5\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"6\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"7\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"8\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"9\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"10\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"11\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"12\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"13\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"14\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"15\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"16\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"17\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"18\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"19\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"20\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"21\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"22\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"23\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"24\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"25\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"26\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"27\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"28\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"29\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"30\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"31\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"32\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"33\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"34\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"35\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"36\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"37\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"38\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"39\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"40\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"41\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"42\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"43\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"44\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"45\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"46\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"47\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"48\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"49\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"50\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"51\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"52\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"53\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"54\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"55\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"56\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"57\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"58\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"59\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"60\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"61\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"62\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"63\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"64\"},{\"enquiry_no\":\"65\"}]
```

Below is the andorid code for sending the data to PHP server

```
// Send POST data request

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
```

PHP server code below

```
<?php

$data = $_POST["data"];

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh)

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP use `stripslashes` to remove "\" backlash :

```
$jsonString= urldecode(stripslashes($data));
```

**OR**

```
$jsonString=json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: I'd like to mention, sometimes when I do that, I have to wrap them in { }. Like: ```echo "{" . @json_encode($data) . "}";``` Sometimes I gotta do this, sometimes I don't. Couldn't tell you why though.